# Using "SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui" my program hangs

Tags: python, pygame, python-import, codeskulptor

This is the link to my guess the number game. http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user38_qz9ak0HMgf_1.py

Upon using " import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui " and running it in python standard library; The program runs without any problem. It even shows the dialog box with buttons, but I am not able to interact with the buttons or the input field. After a while it shows 'Not Responding'.
Please Help!

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The code you linked to seems to work for me (I can tell the codeskulptor site to run the code and the UI elements seem to work). I don't know what you mean by "running it in the python standard library".

Comment: What i meant was that, when i copy-paste the program in python 2.7 IDLE on the system and use " import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui "(Note: After downloading the required modules) for running it on Python 2.7, it runs but gets hung after some time. :/

Answer (score 0):

You must **start the frame**. I made the necessary changes:
http://codeskulptor.org/#user39_UDI8W4cVBK_0.py

You can see differences in codes here:
http://mergely.com/nwDoPwFL

Read also this **compatibility notes**:
https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Compatibility.html